# Qt + Zlib => error LNK2005: _deflate_copyright already defined in QtCored.lib(deflate.obj) zlibstat.lib

Tags: qt, zlib, lnk2005

When I link my application I receive the following message:

> error LNK2005: _deflate_copyright already defined in QtCored.lib(deflate.obj) zlibstat.lib

I'm not sure of the problem, but... I use QT and ZLib. Both are "static libraries". The problem is that the QTCore.lib contains ZLib too!

Project Qt: contains its own version on ZLib.
Project GenericLib: use an external ZLib.lib (cannot be linked to Qt).
Project main: use Qt + Generic lib.

As I say, I'm not sure that it is the problem. But, anyway, if someone has an idea to help me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002757/how-to-add-zlib-to-an-existing-qt-installation
Basically, you don't have to link to it again. Just use the headers and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have try to remove 'zlibstat.lib' but then... I have some other link errors, like "unresolved external symbol _zipWriteInFileInZip@12..."