# CMake : Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: qt, zlib

I'm going to build an open souce chat application named [qutim](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/qutIM?content=83269) (a Qt based applicatoin) . This application needs ZLib but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002757/how-to-add-zlib-to-an-existing-qt-installation) this library is included in Qt itself. But when I want to configure it inside cmake I get this error :

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:85 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  protocols/jabber/jreen/CMakeLists.txt:75 (find_package)
```

I even tried to add two environment variables ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR but it wasn't helpful.
Every suggestion is appriciated!

Comment: That check for jreen searches for an independent zlib. Qt might or might not include zlib, depending on how it's built. I'd install the separate zlib to avoid the hassle.

Comment: The zlib library included in Qt is for Qt's own use. If a project needs zlib, you need to provide one - forget about Qt for the moment.

Answer (score 9):

I met the same problem on build libssh for win32. Fix by cmake ..\libssh -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=....\include -DZLIB_LIBRARY=..\lib\lib

hopes it will help you.

Comment: Worked for me. I added `-DZLIB_LIBRARY:FILEPATH="C:/gtk_compilation/zlib-1.2.11/zlib.lib" -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH="C:/gtk_compilation/zlib-1.2.11"` and all was well. Thank you.