# Uncompress ZLib data in Qt 5.7

Tags: c++, qt

I started moving my project from Qt 5.6 to Qt 5.7 and encounter this problem:

I need to decompress buffer compressed with zlib. But I don't know the size of the uncompressed data, so I can't use Qt function **qUncompress(QByteArray)**. Instead I directly use zlib library included in Qt **#include < QtZlib/zlib.h >** and use **inflate()** function of zlib library.

However as of Qt 5.7 I can not longer include **< QtZlib/zlib.h >**. So is it possible to decompress zlib data with unknown decompressed size using available Qt functions, or link another copy of zlib library is the only way to go?

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23998303/4732082