# zlib1.dll Issue from QT4 to QT5 migration

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, qt4, qt5, zlib

I have migrated a project from QT4 to QT5.7. I am using in Visual Studio 2013 and I have managed to build the program. Though, when I am trying torun the .exe file I get the following error:

[image]

How should I solve this error?

Comment: Did it help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989823/zlib-in-qt-qtzlib-not-present ?

Comment: @rightaway717 I have read this post, though it did not helped me. I do not have a .pro file in my project so I cannot use the "INCLUDEPATH" solution mentioned.

Comment: the solution is not using INCLUDEPATH for that, but u can see from the accepted answer is to use your own zlib library, whatever way you can include it into your project. And you have a linker error, not compiler, so INCLUDEPATH has nothing to do with that. You have to provide a runtime zlib library (install it on your system), you may not need to add anything to the project

Comment: @rightaway717 I have included the zlib library in my own system, though the problem remains still the same. Do I have to include the zlib1.dll file in the project? I have installed it with MinGW.

Comment: can u try to put the zlib1.dll into the directory with your .exe file and see if it finds the library?
If not, you can try this program http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to see if any other dependancies are missing

Comment: @rightaway717 thank you for your help. I have put the .dll in the same directory with the .exe file and now the error has been dissolved.  
Now I get the errors of missing QtOpenGL4.dll, QtSvg4.dll, QtGui4.dll, do you have any idea why I get these errors?

Comment: that most likely means that you are still linking the project against Qt4. Run the "dependency walker" tool I advised you and it will show you what libraries it links against and which are missing.