# What is the correct way to include zLib in a Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, zlib, qmake

I'm trying to get this Qt project building, but I'm running into these `Undefined symbol` error having to do with zLib:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_z_crc32", referenced from:
      ZipPrivate::createEntry(QFileInfo const&, QString const&, Zip::CompressionLevel) in zip.o
      UnzipPrivate::extractFile(QString const&, ZipEntryP const&, QIODevice*, QFlags<UnZip::ExtractionOption>) in unzip.o
  "_z_deflate", referenced from:
      ZipPrivate::createEntry(QFileInfo const&, QString const&, Zip::CompressionLevel) in zip.o
  "_z_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      ZipPrivate::createEntry(QFileInfo const&, QString const&, Zip::CompressionLevel) in zip.o
  "_z_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      ZipPrivate::createEntry(QFileInfo const&, QString const&, Zip::CompressionLevel) in zip.o
  "_z_get_crc_table", referenced from:
      ZipPrivate::ZipPrivate() in zip.o
      UnzipPrivate::UnzipPrivate() in unzip.o
  "_z_inflate", referenced from:
      UnzipPrivate::extractFile(QString const&, ZipEntryP const&, QIODevice*, QFlags<UnZip::ExtractionOption>) in unzip.o
  "_z_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      UnzipPrivate::extractFile(QString const&, ZipEntryP const&, QIODevice*, QFlags<UnZip::ExtractionOption>) in unzip.o
  "_z_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      UnzipPrivate::extractFile(QString const&, ZipEntryP const&, QIODevice*, QFlags<UnZip::ExtractionOption>) in unzip.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have a `zlib` folder in my project and I'm including `zlib/zconf.h` (the zlib directory is a symlink to `/usr/local/opt/zlib/include`) and `zlib/zlib.h`. I'm including these lines in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/zlib/include
HEADERS += /usr/local/opt/zlib/include/zconf.h
HEADERS += /usr/local/opt/zlib/include/zlib.h
```

And here is how I'm importing zlib:

```
#include <zlib/zconf.h>
#include <zlib/zlib.h>
```

I'm very new to Qt, C++, and zLib. What is the correct way of including zlib in a Qt/C++ project?

Comment: How have you installed zlib?

Comment: You need to add `-lzlib` to LIBS

Comment: change to `LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -lz`

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried that, but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: @CongMa How exactly? I tried `LIBS += -lzlib` but I get this error: `ld: library not found for -lzlib`

Comment: I think you have installed the 32bit version of the library, and you are compiling for a 64bit architecture.

Comment: @eyllanesc I was thinking it might be something like that. I installed it using `brew install zlib`. Not sure why it would install the 32bit version.

Comment: QtCreator provides a way to include it quickly, I recommend using it, in the following link it shows how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611265/6622587

Comment: Have you actually build zlib?

Answer (score 0):

Please try next solutions.

1. [zlib in Qt - QtZlib not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989823/zlib-in-qt-qtzlib-not-present)
2. You can found by text search where defined ZipPrivate::createEntry and UnzipPrivate::extractFile and include that files  into INCLUDEPATH or HEADERS.
3. Error looks like lost option for CONFIG variable. Found option that will switch on support zlib in your project. I don't know that option at the moment.