# How can zlib.cpp in boost ever compile?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, qt-creator

I compile my Android project in QtCreator with `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. This means I include all boost `.cpp` files right into my project. When I converted this project to Visual Studio project to try to build it for windows, one boost file started to cause problems: **`zlib.cpp`**

It contains these lines:

```
#include "zlib.h"   // Jean-loup Gailly's and Mark Adler's "zlib.h" header.
                    // To configure Boost to work with zlib, see the 
                    // installation instructions here:
                    // http://boost.org/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=7
```

I don't understand how is this ever meant to compile, since the directory looks like this:

[image: image description]

That means the `zlib.h` is not there and cannot be included. Visual Studio experiences exactly that problem:

```
boost159\libs\iostreams\src\zlib.cpp(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory
```

At the same time, it compiles all right in QtCreator with qmake. So what's going on, how can it ever work? And how to make it work in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I expect you will have to compile zlib yourself and add the header location to you additional include folders. http://www.zlib.net/

Comment: @drescherjm Do you have any idea why does it work in QtCreator without any problems (I didn't configure it up).

Comment: Its possible that the mingw that qtcreator includes for its compiler contains zlib. I do not have QtCreator under windows to here to check. You may want to search your system for zlib.h

Comment: This post seems to say that zlib is in Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4013659/487892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to have the library dependencies installed.

This means that `zlib.h` is in your system's include directories.

Your IDE might silently add some convenient libraries your include paths.

Comment: Yeah, the related aspect is that quoted include does also search in include directories - I thought it only searches in the directory where source file is located.