# add QuaZip to project

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am trying to add QuaZip to my project but getting build errors, all related to undefined references.
Here's the first error and they mostly relate to the archive functions in the extractAll function.

error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6QuaZip13goToFirstFileEv'

Here's the additions to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/quazip/
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/zlib/include/
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/zlib/lib/
LIBS += -L$$PWD/zlib/lib/
```

In the quazip subfolder I have all the headers for quazip.
In the line after that in the libs folder I have the .a for quazip.
The zilib subfolder has the zlib developer files.

Here's the functions I'm trying to use:

```
void Utilities::updateFiles_zip()
{
    currentDownloads.clear();
    init_files();

    QString error = "";
    QString file = "LAE-Intnl-numbers-new.zip";

    error = checkForUpdates(file);

    if (error != "")
    {
        errorMessage = error;
        if (DEBUG)
            qDebug() << "error = {" <<  error << "}";       
        return; 
    }

    QString filename = downloadPath + "LAE-Intnl-numbers-new.zip";
    QuaZip *zip_file = new QuaZip(filename);
    extractAll(zip_file, inputPath);
}


void Utilities::extractAll( QuaZip *archive, QString destFileFolder )
{
    // extracts all files from the archive and saves
    // them onto disk
    //
    // just a simple implementation for evaluation.
    // error handling has not been implemented yet!

    for( bool f = archive->goToFirstFile(); f; f = archive->goToNextFile() )
    {
        // set source file in archive
        QString filePath = archive->getCurrentFileName();
        QuaZipFile zFile( archive->getZipName(), filePath );
        // open the source file
        zFile.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );
        // create a bytes array and write the file data into it
        QByteArray ba = zFile.readAll();
        // close the source file
        zFile.close();
        // set destination file
        QString destFilePath = destFileFolder +  filePath;
        QFile dstFile( destFilePath );
        // open the destination file
        dstFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text );
        // write the data from the bytes array into the destination file
        dstFile.write( ba.data() );
        //close the destination file
        dstFile.close();
    }
}
```

Edit: Got it to complie, but application is crashing now.

Here's how my .pro file looks:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-04-20T05:16:50
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Lottery
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/zlib/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/zlib/lib
LIBS += -L$$PWD/zlib/lib

LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lquazip

SOURCES += main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        Games.cpp \
        Config.cpp \
        ProcessNumbers.cpp \
        SortMethods.cpp \
        Headers.cpp \
        AnalysisMethods.cpp \
        CombosMethods.cpp \
        CheckMatchesMethods.cpp \
        MatchesMethods.cpp \
        RandomMethods.cpp \
        form.cpp \
        Utilities.cpp \
        numbersranksavgsdiffs.cpp \
        MatchesMethods_LM.cpp



HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    AnalysisMethods.h \
    Config.h \
    Headers.h \
    ProcessNumbers.h \
    SortMethods.h \
    dates.h \
    sorts.h \
    update.h \
    Games.h \
    CombosMethods.h \
    combos.h \
    gameballs.h \
    comboscheck.h \
    CheckMatchesMethods.h \
    MatchesMethods.h \
    RandomMethods.h \
    checkmatches.h \
    progress.h \
    form2.h \
    matches.h \
    random.h \
    Utilities.h \
    pointers.h \
    diffs.h \
    numbersranksavgsdiffs.h \
    MatchesMethods_LM.h \
    matches_lm.h \
    analysis.h

include(quazip.pri)


FORMS    += \
    mainwindow.ui \
    dates.ui \
    update.ui \
    sorts.ui \
    combos.ui \
    gameballs.ui \
    comboscheck.ui \
    checkmatches.ui \
    form2.ui \
    progress.ui \
    matches.ui \
    random.ui \
    diffs.ui \
    matches_lm.ui \
    analysis.ui

QT += network

QT += core gui widgets

QT += concurrent

#QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += -Wl,--stack,32000000

#QMAKE_LFLAGS += /STACK:32000000

#QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS = /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01

RC_ICONS = currency_blue_dollar.ico
```

and here is my quazip.pri looks:

```
#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/quazip
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/quazip

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/quazip/headers


HEADERS += $$PWD/quazip/headers/minizip_crypt.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/ioapi.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/JlCompress.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quaadler32.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quachecksum32.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quacrc32.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quagzipfile.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quaziodevice.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazipdir.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazipfile.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazipfileinfo.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazip_global.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazip.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/quazipnewinfo.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/unzip.h \
        $$PWD/quazip/headers/zip.h
#        $$PWD/zlib/include/zlib.h

#SOURCES += $$PWD/quazip/qioapi.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/JlCompress.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quaadler32.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quacrc32.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quagzipfile.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quaziodevice.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quazip.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quazipdir.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quazipfile.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quazipfileinfo.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/quazipnewinfo.cpp \
#           $$PWD/quazip/unzip.c \
#           $$PWD/quazip/zip.c
```

Comment: I think you need to add one more linker flag to your `LIBS`. Use lowercase L and the library name - something like `-llibqua.a` depending on the actual name of the lib.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Got it to build but application is crashing now. Did not make any changes except for QuaZip. See my edit above for the changes to get it to build.

Comment: The coredump information would be helpful.

Comment: I used a quazip.dll I got from a Qt MinGW build. All problems are solved. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

why not just put the source code in any directory you like. For example, 3rdparty:

```
|-- project.pro
|-- ....
|-- 3rdparty\
|     |-- QuaZip\
|     |
```

Add following line to your qmake project file:

```
include(3rdparty/quazip/blob/master/quazip.pri)
```

and `qmake` will do the job

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Got it to build but application is crashing now. Did not make any changes except for QuaZip. See my edit above for the changes to get it to build. I tried using the sources before but kept getting hundreds of build errors for undefined refernces. I didn't have the complete QuaZip folder but just the sources and headers inthe .pri file.

Comment: @te7 refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002757/how-to-add-zlib-to-an-existing-qt-installation

Comment: I used a quazip.dll I got from a Qt MinGW build. All problems are solved. Thanks for your help.